# Como apagar o botão view cart no submenu do carrinho (ver imagem) -woocomerce

Tags: html5, wordpress, woocommerce

Boas pessoal eu queria apagar o botão que diz view cart como podem visualizar na imagem abaixo.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Deixo o site que estou a desenvolver em baixo :

ttu.awd.pt/home

Eu sou um pouco noob no wordpress preciso que me expliquem detalhadamente o que fazer obrigado .

Não consigo mesmo encontrar o ficheiro que contem esse submenu .

Obrigado pela vossa ajuda.

Answer (score 0):

O seu link não está disponivel.

No entanto sugiro que faça o seguinte.

Faça um "inspect element" sobre esse botao e pege algo que o identifique - id ou a class. 
De seguida aplique um CSS na opção de customizar o seu template.

```
#idDoBotaonalocalizaoquequer{display:none!important;}
```

Isto deve resolver.